# Save a plot to a JPEG file in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab, image-processing, plot, save

I have designed the following GUI in which there are an axes. I want to save the plot drawn inside them to a jpeg file. However, the file obtained is an image of the overall figure window. This is my code:

```
    X = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
    Y = sin(X);
    fh = figure;
    Pan1 = uipanel(fh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 0.5 1],'title',...
        'Panel1');
    Pan2 = uipanel(fh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.5 0 0.5 1],'title',...
        'Panel2');
    haxes = axes('Parent',Pan2,'Units', 'normalized','Position',...
        [0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5]);
    hplot = plot(haxes,X,Y);
    xlabel(haxes,'Time (second)');
    ylabel(haxes,'Amplitude (meter)');
    title(haxes,'Sine function');
    FileName = uiputfile('*.jpg','Save as');
    saveas(hplot,FileName);
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but why jpg-format for a plot? That would introduce artefacts.

Comment: @bos: I think the best format for an image is jpeg. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: I use .png for all of my MATLAB plots I want to save as images. They come out much cleaner than .jpg. This [article](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/png-vs-jpg) explains: "PNG works best for vector type graphics with hard lines."

Comment: @Doresoom: Thank you for your comment and link provided.

Comment: Maybe "Save a subplot to a JPEG file in Matlab." would be a better title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`saveas` only saves figures, not individual plots.

If you have a subplot, or a plot within a uicontrol like you have, you can make a temporary copy of the plot, save it, then delete the temporary copy:

```
ftmp = figure; atmp = axes;
copyobj(hplot, atmp);
saveas(ftmp, FileName);
delete(ftmp);
```

If you don't want the temporary copy to flash up on the screen during the copying step, you can use the `'Position'` property of the figure to create it off-screen.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer is correct for my initial purpose of creating the image file. However, I also need that xlabel, ylabel and title's labels are shown on it. This is the reason why I have answered my own question basing me on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Sam's answer is spot on, I just want to add that Matlab is smart enough to know what kind of file you want to save by inspecting the `FileName` string variable. If you set `FileName` to something that ends in `.jpg`, you can save a jpeg. Check out the [`saves` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html) to see all the other possible filetypes.

Answer (score 1):

When using the saveas function to create jpeg the resolution is different as when manually saving the figure with File-->Save As..., It's more recommended to use hgexport instead, as follows:

```
hgexport(gcf, 'figure1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');
```

This will do exactly as manually saving the figure.

source:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PT49C/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-1PT49C

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based on [Sam Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169781/sam-roberts) and [eykanal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168775/eykanal)'s answer:

```
X = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
Y = sin(X);
fh = figure('toolbar','none','menubar','none');
Pan1 = uipanel(fh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 0.5 1],'title',...
    'Panel1');
Pan2 = uipanel(fh,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.5 0 0.5 1],'title',...
    'Panel2');
haxes = axes('Parent',Pan2,'Units', 'normalized','Position',...
[0.125 0.1 0.75 0.75]);
hplot = plot(haxes,X,Y);
xlabel(haxes,'Time (second)');
ylabel(haxes,'Amplitude (meter)');
title(haxes,'Sine function');
FileName = uiputfile('*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg;*.tif','Save as');
ftmp = figure('Menu','none','Toolbar','none','Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[-1000 -1000 1 1]); 
new_axes = copyobj(haxes, ftmp);
set(new_axes,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);
saveas(ftmp, FileName);
delete(ftmp);
delete(fh);
```